# Cropping very large fits files using specified boundaries

Tags: image, crop, astronomy, fits, astropy

I have a large fits file (over 30,000 x 30,000) pixels. [IRAF](http://iraf.noao.edu/) cannot handle this size of image. How can one crop a file of this size while retaining correct header information, as IRAF does when using its standard cropping mode?

Comment: Your question should contain specific code problems. They way your question is currently framed, it would be a matter of opinion or too broad for this site.

Answer (score 9):

You can do this sort of cropping with `astropy.io.fits`, though it's not trivial yet.  Since `astropy.io.fits` uses [memory mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file) by default, it should be able to handle arbitrarily large files (within some practical limits).  If you want non-python solutions, look [here](http://tdc-www.harvard.edu/postage_stamp/postage_stamp.html) for details about postage stamp creation.

```
from astropy.io import fits
from astropy import wcs
f = fits.open('file.fits')
w = wcs.WCS(f[0].header)
newf = fits.PrimaryHDU()
newf.data = f[0].data[100:-100,100:-100]
newf.header = f[0].header
newf.header.update(w[100:-100,100:-100].to_header())
```

See also [this pull request](https://github.com/astropy/astropy/pull/3823), which implements a convenience `Cutout2D` function, though this is not yet available in a released version of astropy.  Its usage can be seen in the [documentation](http://astropy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/astropy.nddata.utils.Cutout2D.html), modified to include WCS:

```
from astropy.nddata import Cutout2D
position = (49.7, 100.1)
shape = (40, 50)
cutout = Cutout2D(f[0].data, position, shape, wcs=w)
```

There are more examples [here](http://astropy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/nddata/utils.html#d-cutout-images)

Comment: The question and answer are quite old, so I just want to add that Cutout2D has been now for long in the stable branch of astropy, so for stable documentation see here: https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.nddata.utils.Cutout2D.html